# Buttons have same class - one submits form, the other runs the jQuery fine

Tags: jquery, forms

I have tried everything I can think of.

**Note**: I have tried setting `<button type="button">` and it did not fix it.

The initial button, with the same class and same call to the jQuery function, works completely fine.  The remove button works.  It's only the second add input field button that submits the form.

Here is the jFiddle I set up so you can test it's functionality right away:

*Note in the JSFiddle if you continue to click the top add button, it adds more input fields.*

[JSFiddle Demo of the code](https://jsfiddle.net/baga4b3s/)

**The jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 100;
    var wrapper = $(".wrapper");
    var add_button = $(".new-skill-field");

    var i = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (i < max_fields) { 
            i++; 
            $(wrapper).append('<div><label>Skill Name:</label><input type="text" name="skillName[]" required><label>Skill Level:</label><input type="text" name="skillLevel[]" class="input-small" required><button class="new-skill-field">Add Another Skill</button><button class="remove-skill">Remove This Skill</button></div>');
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove-skill", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        i--;
    });
});
```

**The HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <label>Skill Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="skillName[]" id="skillName" required>
        <label>Skill Level:</label>
        <input type="text" name="skillLevel[]" id="skillLevel" class="input-small" required>
        <button class="new-skill-field">Add Another Skill</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might check `on` event for dynamically created DOM elements

Comment: you have to bind after you append it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `on` event and listen on `document`

```
$(document).on("click", ".new-skill-field", function(e) {
}
```

Check this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/baga4b3s/2/)

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!  Ted's for some reason was causing the Remove Input Field buttons to either add new input fields or not work entirely for some reason, which is odd since his code seems to simply use the variable and you use the actual class in the .on

Comment: For some reason now it isn't passing the arrays in the form into the $_POST[''], regardless how many I enter it only returns the first one.

Answer (score 0):

change the event binding to document level so that all future controls will get picked-up, too

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 100;
  var wrapper = $(".wrapper");
  var add_button = $(".new-skill-field");

  var i = 1;
  $(document).on('click', ".new-skill-field", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (i < max_fields) {
      i++;
      $(wrapper).append('<div><label>Skill Name:</label><input type="text" name="skillName[]" required><label>Skill Level:</label><input type="text" name="skillLevel[]" class="input-small" required><button class="new-skill-field">Add Another Skill</button><button class="remove-skill">Remove This Skill</button></div>');
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove-skill", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    i--;
  });
});
```

Comment: For some reason the Remove Input Field buttons are acting spontaneous with this, either adding new input fields or doing nothing at all - but never removing the fields.

Comment: you're right, I thought that `add_button` was equal to `".new-skill-field"` but it was actually equal to `$(".new-skill-field")`... that's why it wasn't working